# How do I create a new model, related to an existing model, using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sti

If I have the following models, which use STI:

```
# Organization Model
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, :through => :questions
end

# Base Question Model
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :answers
end

# Subclass of Question
class TextQuestion < Question

end

# Subclass of Question
class CheckboxQuestion < Question

end
```

What is the correct way to build a new object that is a particular type of `Question` **and** also relates to `Organization`? Or in other words, if I have an organization, and I want that organization to have a new `CheckboxQuestion`, can I use the regular builder methods?

For example, I was expecting to be able to do:

```
org = Organization.last
org.text_questions.build(:question_text => "What is your name?")
```

... but this gives me an `NoMethodError: undefined method text_questions`  error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Organization` model is not aware of the classes that inherit from the `Question` so you can initiate/create question instances in this way. In order to initiate/create questions of specific type, you have to explicitly set it yourself. For example:

```ruby
organization = Organization.where(...).last
organization.questions.build(question_text: 'text', type: 'TextQuestion')
```

You could define multiple `has_many *_questions` at the `Organization` class, but it feels like a bad design and things will get out of hand if you end up having a lot of `Question` subclasses in your application.

Comment: So, in your example above, it isn't poor technique to manually specify the new question's `type`?

Comment: I think both approaches introduce potential complexity/problems (IMO) that is partially why some people choose to avoid STI in many cases. If there is repeated logic/code you might think about other options such as Concerns (include Concerns::Question), etc. Just for future reading/consideration. :)

Comment: @GregMatthewCrossley I think it's not, because by not defining multiple associations based on type, `Organization` doesn't know much about what's going on with `Question` and its subclasses. It knows only about the interface `Question` provides, which is a good thing. I think this is the cleanest way of doing things, but it's just my opinion.

Comment: Also, as @DavidStump said, both approaches introduce potential problems and it might makes sense to look into alternative options such as polymorphism/composition over class inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure without seeing your `Organization` model, however this might be what you are looking for:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :test_questions
  has_many :checkbox_questions
end
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need to set up a `has_many` relationship between `Organization` and all of the sub-classes of `Question`?

Comment: Along the lines of what Ioannis mentioned - the Organization model does now know anything about `TextQuestion` specifically. You either need to define has_many relationships, methods, or explicitly define it yourself as he demonstrates. Whichever seems the most straightforward to you.